# syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Tags: awk

i have below sniipet in my shell script it is throwing syntax error any way to solve it

```
iftop -i eth1 -t -s 1 -n -N > ifTop.txt
th=`awk '{print $8}' ifTop.txt | cut -c 5-6`
```

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and do what it suggests, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 for why. if you want help debugging a syntax error message then obviously you should include that error message in your question. Chances are the error is caused by something earlier in your script than the snippet you've shown us - make sure to show a complete (but **minimal**) script that can reproduce the error messages you want help to debug.

Comment: Is that your _complete_ script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get a syntax error on Ubuntu, but I think you have another problem: `iftop` produces multiple lines of output, and it seems that you want to extract the top value.

To take the 3rd line use `NR==3 {print $8}`.

I don't see 8 fields on my output either.